# Opening a socket using Wifi connection in android

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, can-bus

I have a [PCan wireless device](http://www.peak-system.com/PCAN-Wireless-Gateway.331.0.html) that can play the role as which they called "Micro Access Point". The concept is to make it router and other devices connect to it. With this connection I can send/receive CAN frames using TCP or UDP. The main Goal is to connect to this Wifi and open a socket and send/ receive TPC/UPD frames in android M.

I wrote an android activity which search for all available Wifis and connects to it with a button which i can connect successfully.

After connection I tried to open a socket but it failed. I tried it also with different timeouts:

```
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                for (int i = 0; i <= 255; ++i) { // I wrote this for loop to check all possibilities!
                    String ip = "192.168.1." + i;
                    try {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Try ip: " + ip);
                        Socket socket = new Socket();
                        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip, 50000), 100);
                        Log.e(TAG, "Connected!");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Exception is catched!");
                    }
                }

            }
        }).start();
    }
});
```

Can somebody tell me how to open a socket?
Here are the infos on the device:

ip: 192.168.1.10

port: 50000

gateway:192.168.1.199

UPDATE:

I don't know if I am on the right way to overcome this problem. Very short to say: I want to connect to this wireless device and send/receive tcp and UPD frames. Unfortunately I have a very limited knowledge on networking.

Comment: Is this a socket question or a "how to connect to a wifi network" question?   Either way, there seems to be a lot of irrelevant information.   If you're not on a network, how to make a socket doesn't matter.  And if you ARE on a network, whether it's a wifi network doesn't matter when making a socket.

Comment: @xaxxon I am C++ guy with no networking experience. So maybe the question is ambiguous. The Question is how can I send/receive data on this device? Am I on the right road?

Comment: Probably?   But you've really put two questions in here.  One is "how to I connect to a wifi network" and another is "how do I make a socket".   Please limit the post to just one question (you can make another post if needed)

Comment: I don't know PCan wireless device do but TCP/IP connection is establish by Three-Way Handshake procedure. What you need to check
1. your android device and PCan wireless device are on same network.
2. PCan wireless device is act as tcp/ip  server
3.PCan wireless device at which port its listening for incoming connection
 requests.

NOTE: PCan wireless device can be accessed over internet then first step is not needed only your device then should have internet access.

Comment: if you want to connect your device some specific WiFi network programmatically then you should check WifiManager and these methods especially 
1. addNetwork
2. startScan
3. getScanResults

Comment: If your credentials are right and you are on the same network, use `socket.getInputStream()` to monitor the incoming traffic, and use `socket.getOutputStream()` to write data into the socket (eg. send data to the other client). I recommend to increase your timeout period as 100ms seems a bit too short. Sockets are used for TCP, if you want UDP protocol use DatagramSockets.

Comment: @YasirAli To answer your questions: 1. I don't know what you mean they are on the same network. I connect to pcan and it plays the AP role. and there is no internet. 2. Yes, the device is acting as server and 3. port 50000 for listening (also I can define it as well) and handshake is off. Stupid question: i connects to a wifi. should i always open a socket for sending data with TCP protocol?

Comment: @EndreBörcsök Handshake by AP is off. I connect to the AP (wireless device that acts as server) programmatically. Try to open a socket which is unsuccessfull. answer yours: 1. What do you mean on the same network? they should  be isnt it? 2. I cannot connect a socket so how can i use `socket.getInputStream()`

Comment: Same network mean they should have same network mass

Comment: @YasirAli I believe they have the same network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the wireless router only accepts the static IPs. Using a static IP and gateway solved the problem.